# how to decrease the height of table of class UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using table view in a view controller which is `UITableViewController`. I am trying to set the height of table by

```
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backImageView];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

but it is not working.
It doesn't have XIB
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: where do you put this code ? is there other code modifying any other property of your tableView ?

Comment: you need to give more information. do you do anything more on your view ? is your TVC set in a XIB ?

Comment: it is not having xib. it is set programmatically

Comment: Hi Heena, are you actually alloc'ing and initialising your tableView anywhere?  See my answer below if not.  Also run it through the Debugger with a break on the line above and does the tableView have a value other than 0x0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I know you can't do that (IF you push/showModal the tableviewcontroller), the view (in this case a tableview) of viewcontrollers is resized automatically to the screen size (- status bar, navigationbar and tabbar). You can however set `contentOffset` and `contentInset`.

In your case this should work (might need to change the values):

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0 /*top*/, 0/*left*/, 160/*bottom*/, 0/*right*/);
```

Answer (score -1):

Difficult to say without some more detail.  For instance, are you creating your UITableView object in your LoadView?

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
```

You also need to make sure you are adding your tableView to the view controller's view:

```
[self addSubView:tableView];
```

Hope this helps, but a bit more detail in your question would enable a more thorough answer.  i.e., what does not work, etc.

Dave

Comment: i tried this out but not affecting table. may be because it is already tableviewcontroller